# Are there any loan options for the international students in the US?

Tags: united-states, loans, student-loan, student

I am an international student of one of the university of California campuses. I study PhD and am a fully funded student with around $30,000 annual salary(before tax).

I need about $5000 in cash and like to know is there any option for me?
If so, what is the best option with lower APR and longer payment terms?

Comment: It will be useful if you say why you need it.

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on your specific details

1. Talk to your financial aid department in the University. They typically know all loan programs that may be available to you.
2. Talk to one or two local banks. The bank will want to see some sort of collateral, so you will have deep dive into the details.
3. Consider taking up a part time job on or off campus (if you contract allows it). Maybe you can scrounge a paid internship somewhere.
4. If none of these work out, you may consider asking friends or family for help. This depends a bit for how long you need it and what your ability and time frame for repayment would look like.
5. Stay away from credit cards and short term loans from dubious sources. These will only get you into trouble